# Pyaudio record audio using non-blocking callback

Tags: python, audio, keyboard

I am currently trying to make a simple script which records while a key is being pressed. I need to generate some data, so the intention with the script was to prompt the terminal with an sentence, and when the speaker presses a key will the script start recording, at which the speaker reads the sentence. when the sentence has been spoken, and recorded should a key release stop the recording and thus create the audio file..

This is what i currently have:

```
from pynput import keyboard
import time
import pyaudio
import wave

CHUNK = 8192
FORMAT = pyaudio.paInt16
CHANNELS = 2
RATE = 44100
RECORD_SECONDS = 5
WAVE_OUTPUT_FILENAME = "output.wav"

p = pyaudio.PyAudio()
frames = []

def callback(in_data, frame_count, time_info, status):
    return (in_data, pyaudio.paContinue)

class MyListener(keyboard.Listener):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MyListener, self).__init__(self.on_press, self.on_release)
        self.key_pressed = None

        self.stream = p.open(format=FORMAT,
                             channels=CHANNELS,
                             rate=RATE,
                             input=True,
                             frames_per_buffer=CHUNK,
                             stream_callback = self.callback)
        print self.stream.is_active()

    def on_press(self, key):
        if key == keyboard.Key.cmd_l:
            self.key_pressed = True

    def on_release(self, key):
        if key == keyboard.Key.cmd_l:
            self.key_pressed = False

    def callback(self,in_data, frame_count, time_info, status):
        if self.key_pressed == True:
            return (in_data, pyaudio.paContinue)
        elif self.key_pressed == False:
            return (in_data, pyaudio.paComplete)
        else:
            return (in_data,pyaudio.paAbort)


listener = MyListener()
listener.start()
started = False

while True:
    time.sleep(0.1)
    if listener.key_pressed == True and started == False:
        started = True
        listener.stream.start_stream()
        print "start Stream"

    elif listener.key_pressed == False and started == True:
        print "Something coocked"
        listener.stream.stop_stream()
        listener.stream.close()
        p.terminate()

        wf = wave.open(WAVE_OUTPUT_FILENAME, 'wb')
        wf.setnchannels(CHANNELS)
        wf.setsampwidth(p.get_sample_size(FORMAT))
        wf.setframerate(RATE)
        wf.writeframes(b''.join(frames))
        wf.close()

        started = False
```

I seem to have problems with the frames keep dropping, and nothing is being recorded. I made the implementation using a callback function, as I thought maybe the keyboard thread might have been blocking it, so just to be sure.. but nothing seem to be recorded, since I keep getting the IOerror... what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I know that this question is from 4 years ago but I found it in my searches so I am going to put what helped me after I found this dead question.

I used this little wrapper: https://gist.github.com/sloria/5693955

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
'''recorder.py
Provides WAV recording functionality via two approaches:

Blocking mode (record for a set duration):
>>> rec = Recorder(channels=2)
>>> with rec.open('blocking.wav', 'wb') as recfile:
...     recfile.record(duration=5.0)

Non-blocking mode (start and stop recording):
>>> rec = Recorder(channels=2)
>>> with rec.open('nonblocking.wav', 'wb') as recfile2:
...     recfile2.start_recording()
...     time.sleep(5.0)
...     recfile2.stop_recording()
'''
import pyaudio
import wave

class Recorder(object):
    '''A recorder class for recording audio to a WAV file.
    Records in mono by default.
    '''

    def __init__(self, channels=1, rate=44100, frames_per_buffer=1024):
        self.channels = channels
        self.rate = rate
        self.frames_per_buffer = frames_per_buffer

    def open(self, fname, mode='wb'):
        return RecordingFile(fname, mode, self.channels, self.rate,
                            self.frames_per_buffer)

class RecordingFile(object):
    def __init__(self, fname, mode, channels, 
                rate, frames_per_buffer):
        self.fname = fname
        self.mode = mode
        self.channels = channels
        self.rate = rate
        self.frames_per_buffer = frames_per_buffer
        self._pa = pyaudio.PyAudio()
        self.wavefile = self._prepare_file(self.fname, self.mode)
        self._stream = None

    def __enter__(self):
        return self

    def __exit__(self, exception, value, traceback):
        self.close()

    def record(self, duration):
        # Use a stream with no callback function in blocking mode
        self._stream = self._pa.open(format=pyaudio.paInt16,
                                        channels=self.channels,
                                        rate=self.rate,
                                        input=True,
                                        frames_per_buffer=self.frames_per_buffer)
        for _ in range(int(self.rate / self.frames_per_buffer * duration)):
            audio = self._stream.read(self.frames_per_buffer)
            self.wavefile.writeframes(audio)
        return None

    def start_recording(self):
        # Use a stream with a callback in non-blocking mode
        self._stream = self._pa.open(format=pyaudio.paInt16,
                                        channels=self.channels,
                                        rate=self.rate,
                                        input=True,
                                        frames_per_buffer=self.frames_per_buffer,
                                        stream_callback=self.get_callback())
        self._stream.start_stream()
        return self

    def stop_recording(self):
        self._stream.stop_stream()
        return self

    def get_callback(self):
        def callback(in_data, frame_count, time_info, status):
            self.wavefile.writeframes(in_data)
            return in_data, pyaudio.paContinue
        return callback


    def close(self):
        self._stream.close()
        self._pa.terminate()
        self.wavefile.close()

    def _prepare_file(self, fname, mode='wb'):
        wavefile = wave.open(fname, mode)
        wavefile.setnchannels(self.channels)
        wavefile.setsampwidth(self._pa.get_sample_size(pyaudio.paInt16))
        wavefile.setframerate(self.rate)
        return wavefile
```

Then, all you have to do to record non-blocking is the following:

```
with rec.open(wav_output_filename, 'wb') as recfile2:
        recfile2.start_recording()
        time.sleep(5.0)
        recfile2.stop_recording()
```